# Create Union of Arrays given as parameters of function

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a union of arrays given as parameters of a function. But I am having this error:

```
Javascript TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {

  var newArr = arguments[0];

  //Loop arguments
  for (let i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
    console.log(arguments[i]);

    //Loop second argument values
    for (let y =0; y<arguments[i+1].length; y++){

      //Loop first argument values
      for (let z=0; z<arguments[i].length; z++){
        if (arguments[i+1][y] !== arguments[i][z]){
          newArr.push(arguments[i+1][y]);
        }

      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
```

The output I want is [1, 3, 2, 5 ,4] , which is a union of unique values from the 3 arrays here. I'm getting this error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Length of first array has no relationship to length of arguments

Answer (score 1):

From i can understand you want to combine three array into one removing the duplicates. Then the following code will help you.

```
var a = ["1","2","3"];
var b = ["3","4","5"];
var c = ["4","5","6"];

var d = a.concat(b).concat(c);
var set = new Set(d);

d = Array.from(set);

console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ES6 features`

```js
function unionArg(...args){
let newtab = []

//Destructuring of each arg which is an array
args.forEach(arg=>{
  newtab = [...arg,...newtab]
})

//Having all the items in a single array, we will keep only distincts elements
newtab = [...new Set(newtab)]

console.log("unique values:" + newtab)

}

unionArg([1,2,3,1],[0,4,1])
```